# How to stop infinite scrolling when database value reaches the end?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Am not an expert programmer. So kindly please help me anybody .Thanks in advance.
Am trying load database value from a table.But when am running the program data scrolling infinitely with duplicating the data again and again.
I need to stop scrolling when table data reaches end.no need of duplicating data.
`

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
# sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM job_posting";
# find out query stat point
$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
# query for page navigation
if( mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > ($page * $limit) ){
  $next = ++$page;
  $hy=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
  $limit=$hy;
}
$query = mysql_query( $sql . " LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  echo 'Page not found!';
  exit();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
    jQuery.ias({
      container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
      item: '.item', // single items
      pagination: '.nav', // page navigation
      next: '.nav a', // next page selector
      loader: '<img src="css/ajaxloader.gif"/>', // loading gif
      triggerPageThreshold: 3 // show load more if scroll more than this
    });
  });
</script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Load While Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1><a href="#">Data load while scroll</a></h1>

  <!-- loop row data -->
  <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
  <div class="item" id="item-<?php echo $row['j_id']?>">
    <h2>
      <span class="num"><?php echo $row['id']?></span>
      <span class="name"><?php echo $row['title'].' '.$row['jobtype']?></span>
    </h2>
    <p><?php echo $row['comp_name']?></p>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile?>

  <!--page navigation-->
  <?php if (isset($next)): ?>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href='again.php?p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
  </div>
  <?php endif?>
</div><!--.wrap-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: Sorry..Its by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the limit to the number of records in the table.

```
  $hy=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));
  $limit=$hy;
```

comment above code 
and set the $limit to any number in start like

```
$limit = 100;
```

Comment: Share the updated code. have you declared the $limit variable before $start variable?

Comment: # find out query stat point
 $limit=100;
$start = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

Comment: kindly share the log of the query created with the start and limit.

Comment: PHP Code looks good now, but you have to work on your JS code. It looks like you are loading the whole page again in the .wrap container.